# How does one define TITLE text of an IMAGE in GWT UiBinder?

Tags: image, gwt, default, uibinder

I'm using GWT Messages for i18n.

In a ui.xml file I define:

```
<g:Image ui:field="logo" url="img.png">
<ui:attribute name='title' ui:description='tooltip for image'/>
</g:Image>
```

On app start-up the GWT environment complains: The enclosing element needs to provide a default value for attribute "title"

I can't find any mention about adding a default value to the . Do you know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

It's not an attribute missing on ui:attribute! Simply add title='the default text' to the g:Image tag.